# Term used to identify the blue bars/rails in the ISS?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, microgravity, terminology

The interior of the ISS is filled with blue bars used by astronauts to secure their feet and remain in one place.  Does NASA have a term for these?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The technical term for them is "handrail".

[image]

Image source: http://www.hunchdesign.com/uploads/2/2/0/9/22093000/restraint_and_mobility_aids.pdf

*IVA (IntraVehicular Activity) Handrail* if you want to be formal.

[image]

Table source: https://snebulos.mit.edu/projects/reference/International-Space-Station/SSP50008RC.pdf

Comment: IVA (IntraVehicular Activity) Handrail-this is the type of designation I thought would come from NASA.

Comment: @Bob516 In case anyone would get them confused with the yellow EVA Handrails, I guess? https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1Cx1aY-G9r0/Ul07Jqqc7NI/AAAAAAAAQxA/Mg7gtFJaLf8/s1600/Walking+in+Space+(25).jpg

Comment: Also, the interface the handrails attach to on each rack is referred to as "seat tracks".